# C# mouse drag function using mouse event flags

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mouse

I am trying to implement a mouse drag function using mouse event flags. I need something like this below:

[image]

I wrote the following code but this does not do the task. Maybe i am missing something?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetCursorPos(900, 250);
        Point p1 = GetCursorPosition();
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
       /* for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            SetCursorPos(720, 310+i*10);
            this.Text = GetCursorPosition().ToString();
        }*/
        SetCursorPos(900, 450);
        Point p2 = GetCursorPosition();
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        //            mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.MOVE), 720, 340, 0, 0);

    }
```

Comment: Actually your code (2 setCursorPos() + 2 mouse_event()) works fine for me. You have same X for setCursorPos calls - is it done by intention?

Comment: Yes i just wanted to check if i can pull a drag line with changing the Y coordinates. Anyways were u able to get the drag as shown in the image?

Comment: Yes, but in my case I have a rectangle because I set 920 as 2nd x. Ah, okay I tried it again. Windows doesn't simply draw a line :) try it manually... Only rectangle is drawn.

Comment: This is weird, when i changed my 2nd x to 920 it did not create any rectangle :/ any help?

Comment: SetCursorPos(900, 250);
            mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetCursorPos(950, 450);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);